# Why is my convolution result shifted when using FFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft, shift, convolution

I'm implementing Convolutions using Radix-2 Cooley-Tukey FFT/FFT-inverse, and my output is correct but shifted upon completion.

My solution is to zero-pad both input size and kernel size to 2^m for smallest possible m, tranforming both input and kernel using FFT, then multiply the two element-wise and transform the result back using FFT-inverse.

As an example on the resulting problem:

```
 0  1  2  3  0  0  0  0
 4  5  6  7  0  0  0  0
 8  9 10 11  0  0  0  0
12 13 14 15  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

with identity kernel

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

becomes

```
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  2  3  0  0  0
 0  4  5  6  7  0  0  0
 0  8  9 10 11  0  0  0
 0 12 13 14 15  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

It seems any sizes of inputs and kernels produces the same shift (1 row and 1 col), but I could be wrong. I've performed the same computations using the online calculator at [this link](http://calculator.vhex.net/calculator/fast-fourier-transform-calculator-fft/2d-discrete-fourier-transform)! and get same results, so it's probably me missing some fundamental knowledge. My available litterature has not helped. So my question, why does this happen?

Comment: Your identity kernel should be size 4x4, right? Place the 1 in index [2,2] (zero-based) and I think you will get a better result.

Comment: Yes the kernel is 4x4, I edited the post accordingly. I'm not sure what you mean by zero-based, but placing the 1 at [2,2] would shift it further. Placing the 1 at [0,0] yields the correct result, but I do not understand why. Is it because I need to circular-shift the kernel so the center (here 1) is at the [0,0] position?

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear. The index of the top leftmost element in an FFT kernel should be -n/2, where n is the number of rows and columns. So for a 4x4 kernel the (0,0) position is located in the third row and the third column.

Comment: Thanks for the respons. However, it's still not clear exactly how I'm supposed to index it, let alone explain why this happens (theoretically). Using a kernel of size 5x5 zero padded to 8x8 generates same result (shifted only 1 row and 1 col). You say the top left should be -n/2. So what you are saying is that what, at the time of performing FFT should be in top left, was at -n/2 before that. Eh. How is -n/2 not a negative index? Is it the shift amount? And how do I determine the kernel anchor/center? Oh jeesh I don't get it... sorry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up finding the answer **why** this happens myself. The answered is given through the definition of the convolution and the indexing that happens there. So by definition the convolution of *s* and *k* is given by

```
(s*k)(x) = sum(s(k)k(x-k),k=-inf,inf)
```

The center of the kernel is **not** "known" by this formula, and thus an abstraction we make. Define *c* as the center of the convolution. When *x-k = c* in the sum, *s(k)* is *s(x-c)*. So the sum containing the interesting product *s(x-c)k(c)* ends up at index *x*. In other words, shifted to the right by *c*.

Answer (score 3):

FFT fast convolution does a circular convolution.  If you zero pad so that both the data and kernel are circularly centered around (0,0) in the same size NxN arrays, the result will also stay centered.  Otherwise any offsets will add.

Comment: So does this mean that say, the kernel [ [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,c,0]], where 'c' is the kernel center, will be shifted exactly 2 rows down and 1 column right? That would kinda make sense to me. Since you say centered around (0,0), I get the impression you mean "relative to the kernel center", which would allow for negative indices. Correct?

Comment: "relative to the kernel center" yes.  with wrap-around negative indices for the "upper left" part.